# Prove that $C_G(H)$ is a normal subgroup of $N_G(H)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I sort of understand the concept of this, but do not know how to write it up.
I know that you want to show that every element of $C_G(H)$ is in $N_G(H)$.

Let $c \in C_G(H)$.  Then c commutes with every element of H so $\forall h\in H, ch = hc $.  Then let $n \in N_G(H).$ Then $n^{-1}hn \in H$

Now I don't know how to put these together to get the desired result.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It's $ncn^{-1}$, not $h^{-1}nh$.

Comment: @KennyLau oops.  fixed

Comment: Sorry, edited again.

Comment: You want $n^{-1}hn\in H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you've already proved that it's a subgroup. I'll prove that it's normal.

Let $c \in C_G(H)$ and $n \in N_G(H)$. We want to show that $ncn^{-1} \in C_G(H)$, i.e. $ncn^{-1}$ commutes with every element in $H$.

Pick an element $h \in H$. Since $H$ is normal in $N_G(H)$ by definition, we can find $k \in H$ such that $hn=nk$. Since $c$ commutes with every element in $H$, it commutes with $k$ in particular, i.e. $ck=kc$. Then:
$$hncn^{-1} = nkcn^{-1} = nckn^{-1} = nc(nk^{-1})^{-1} = nc(h^{-1}n)^{-1} = ncn^{-1}h$$

The last step is from manipulating $hn = nk$ to become $nk^{-1} = h^{-1}n$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $N_G(H)$ act on $H$ by conjugation.  This works since $H \triangleleft N_G(H)$. This induces a  homomorphism from $N_G(H)$ into $Aut(H)$ and has a kernel of $C_G(H)$